# BottomSheetBehavior not in androidX libraries

Tags: android, androidx, bottom-sheet, material-components-android

I was using the `BottomSheetBehavior` with the original support library:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

When I migrated to use the new `androidx` libraries though the `BottomSheetBehavior` is missing. The mapping from the above support library isn't in the [AndroidX Refactoring List](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor) either, but the migration tool removed it.

What am I missing to include the BottomSheetBehavior with the new `androidx` libraries.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // ReactiveX
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.1.0'

    // Android Compatability Libraries
    // Version: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'

    // Android Navigation Component
    // Check here for updated version info - will move to androidx soon.
    // https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha04"

    // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

Answer (score 237, accepted):

It turns out that the refactor tool in Android Studio `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX` didn't correctly migrate the XML for the BottomSheetBehaviour.

The old location was `android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior`, and was not modified by the migration tool. The original XML was:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/player_bottom_sheet_fragment"
    android:name="app.rxsongbrowsertrials.ui.player.PlayerToggleFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    />
```

The new location is `com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior`, so the layout needs to become:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/player_bottom_sheet_fragment"
    android:name="app.rxsongbrowsertrials.ui.player.PlayerToggleFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    />
```

Comment: I spent all day on this one. Hopefully this bubbled up for people to discover more easily.

Comment: In the last update from AS still not corrected this error in the AndroidX migration. Thanks

Answer (score 59):

You could also replace

```
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
or 
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

by

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

Comment: My project, generated from an Android Studio template, didn't have `@string/bottom_sheet_behavior`.  I think I was able to pull it in by adding `implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04"` to my `app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 27):

You have to import the [**Material Components Library**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) provided by Google.

> Material Components for Android is a drop-in replacement for Android's Design Support Library.

Add in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:x.x.x'
```

Then use the class [**`com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetBehavior.md).

In your layout you can use the attribute:

```
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    ..>
```

or

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

Answer (score 2):

For R class

```
com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
```

instead of

```
android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message:

```
Didn't find class "com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehaviour"
```

The only way to solve this was to change the XML:

```
Change:

app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"

Change to:

app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

This solved the problem