# BottomSheetBehavior in AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, bottom-sheet, material-components-android, material-components

I was using **android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior** before, now it's not available in **AndroidX**, some suggest using **com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior** (see this link [BottomSheetBehavior not in androidX libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617186/bottomsheetbehavior-not-in-androidx-libraries)), but it has some bugs and conflicts with NestedScrollView, sometimes it doesn't pass drag to NestedScrollView.
Is there any AndroidX replacement, instead of google material's?

I checked following link from Google, but didn't find replacement for **android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior** : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: support library is available for android pie, you can continue using that meanwhile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new component is inside the [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Use this class:

```
com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
```

Also:

- [Official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetBehavior.md)
- [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior)
- [Code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.java)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

instead of

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```